# Smartcontract/Lottery : Errors during execution of running scripts

Tags: ethereum, brownie

While running the deploy_lottery.py I am getting the following error:
The transactions executes until def start_lottery(). Once it reaches the def enter_lottery the programs stops execution with the following error:
1."sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx."
I am running the script in local development chain with a "id" account.

Comment: Please provide the related code separate of the problem explaining.

Comment: In solidity section this is what may be creating an issue                                     function enter() public payable {
        // Required to be the lottery state to be open during contract execution / call
        require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN);
        //required to enter min of $ 50 - required minimium to enter the lottery
        require(msg.value >= getEntranceFee(), "Not enough ETH!");
        players.push(payable(msg.sender));
    } :     for ref : I have pushed it into github repository : https://github.com/CLTTESTNET/smartcontract-lottery/tree/main/scripts

Comment: Please edit your question and add the related code there. It is hard to read in comments

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code please? mine looks like this and it works
**python**

```
def startLotter():
account = get_account()
lottery = Lottery[-1]
starting_tx = lottery.startLottery({"from": account})
starting_tx.wait(1)
print("The lottery has started!!")
```

**solidity**

```
function startLottery() public onlyOwner
{
    require(lottery_state == LOTTERY_STATE.CLOSED, "lottery already open");
    lottery_state = LOTTERY_STATE.OPEN;
}
```

the function only has to change the state of the lottery but that does require a transaction so you should have the funds.